# Visual Basic, stop program immediately

Tags: vb.net

Using visual basic, I located the source of an exception and enclosed that bit of code inside a try/catch block.

Because of the nature of this exception, the solution is to inform the user that there are steps that the user needs to perform before restarting the program, and immediately close the program (currently using `me.close()`) after the user acknowledges.

The problem is that the program continues to perform actions within the calling method after I send the close command, which causes more problems.

How can I close the program without having those actions run?

What is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Looks you are create window form application, am I right?

Comment: Try `System.Environment.Exit(1)`

Comment: Are you running any background process (multi threading)?,  If is Windows Forms did you setup the Shutdown Mode when the last form closes?

Comment: System.Environment.Exit(1) works.

Comment: Shutdown mode is set to "When startup form closes".

Comment: This program is using Windows Forms. There are no extra background processes running at this particular point in the program.

Comment: Just use `End` anywhere you want to close the app.

Comment: "The problem is that the program continues to perform actions within the calling method after I send the close command" - Did you instruct the method to exit after issuing the `Close` command? i.e. `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function`.

Comment: The most correct way to end the current method at a specific point is with a `Return` statement. Note that doing so will not prevent the calling methods back down the stack from completing. Ideally, you would `Return` in each of those methods where it is appropriate to do so based on an appropriate condition.

Comment: Try to use `End` command. it will terminate the program.

Comment: What's wrong with `application.exit()` to end the program? I thought everyone is using that

Comment: @kiLLua The documentation for the [End Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement) gives reasons why it would not usually be the first choice of a way of ending the program.

Comment: The point where the Try/Catch block is located is at the closest point to the source of the exception. The reason this is done is because this can happen through multiple different method calls, and this exception needs to be handled for all of them. Actions continue to perform **inside the calling method** after the close command is sent. @TnTinMn

Comment: This is arguably not a best practice (adverse side effects can occur), but if you really _really_ **really** need to promptly stop your app without any further processing:`Shell("taskkill.exe /f /t /im " & Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)) : While (1) : End While`